# String comparision never evaluate true in Alfred

Tags: applescript, alfred

I am writing a script for an **Alfred** workflow. However, the string comparison never evaluates true.

The `"{query}"` inside the script does get replaced with a correct `ctext` value type which I can obverse using `display dialog "{query}"` and `display dialog class of "{query}"`.

```
if "{query}" is equal to "a" then
    say "in the a case"
else
    say "in the else case"
end if
```

I have also tried use `if "{query}" = "a" then` but still have the same outcome.

The evaluation keeps falling to the `else` statement.

I am referring the article below when writing the conditional statements.

http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/if-and-if-else-applescript-conditional-statements--mac-45590

[image]

Comment: Check the "**Double quotes**" and "**Backslashes**" checkboxes to set the escaping for AppleScript

Comment: @jackjr300 Thanks for your comments. After checked the escaping checkboxes, the evaluation is still false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not normal, debug it with this script, maybe the string contains an invisible character.

```
set t to "{query}"
display dialog "The ID of 'a' is " & id of "a" --> the  id of a is  97
repeat with i in t -- check the id of every character in "{query}"
    display dialog "The ID of '" & i & "' is " & id of i
end repeat
if t is equal to "a" then
    say "in the a case"
else
    say "in the else case"
end if
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The first char inside `{query}` is an empty char with char code `32`. Your code above is effective for debugging. Thanks.